# How do I add a contact to a group using the API?

Tags: api, groups

I looked in the documentation but I can't seem to find a way to add a contact to a group using the API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open API Explorer - `Support menu > Developer > API Explorer` and use `GroupContact` API to add contacts to group. See an eg in the screenshot below -

[image]

API formed for PHP is -

```
$result = civicrm_api3('GroupContact', 'create', [
  'group_id' => <group_id>,
  'contact_id' => <contact id>,
]);
```